# How to detect database changes in Android Room SQLite local database

Tags: android, android-room

My current Android application employs Room to manage its local SQLIte database.

A particular set of related tables (Parent Children) control the data shown in the rest of my application.

When the user makes any changes to either the Parent and/or Child tables I need to push these changes to my remote server via RESTful API calls.

The Screen flow is as follows:-

```
Main Menu Activity -> Parent Data Activity -> (Multiple Children Activities)
```

I only wish to push changes as the user exits the Parent Data Activity back to the Main Menu.

I need to detect when any columns have been changed on either the Parent Table or any child tables.

I want to ignore when the user has just Viewed the data and made no changes

I also want to ignore when the user has changed a value then changed it back to its original value.

Does SQLite have any built in mechanism to detect "real" table row/column changes?

Or is my only solution to cache Before rows from all of the tables involved and compare these to the After rows as the user exits my Parent Data Activity?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `LiveData` in combination with Room. This would at least give you notifications of values. Allowing you write logic around when to send to your remote server.

Although this wouldn't solve the changed and changed back situation.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#use_livedata_with_room

Comment: LiveData would give me Any change, I need to detect "Real" changes

Comment: Using LiveData in the i/o layer of your app is bad idea. LiveData's purpose is to be used only in the UI layer. One should consider using Rx/Coroutines/Flow instead.